# A method that calls multiple async tasks with error handling, done the right way?

Tags: c#, error-handling, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I've got a method, `CheckForValue()`, that uses named pipes to send a message to another process running locally, and then receive a message from that process, returning a bool indicating if it is equivalent with some value.

I'm concerned that I am not handling `CancellationToken`s and errors correctly. If there any errors (or timeouts), I just want this method to return `false`.

Again, I am not concerned with different methods of IPC, or using a single duplex named pipe, etc. My concern is the error handling and the usage of `CancellationToken`s here.

#### `CheckForValue`

```cs
public async Task<bool> CheckForValue()
{
    int timeout = 300; //300ms should be plenty of time
    try
    {
        using (var getValueCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            var valueTask = GetValueUsingNamedPipe(getValueCancellationTokenSource);
            using (var timeoutCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
            {
                var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(valueTask, Task.Delay(timeout, timeoutCancellationTokenSource.Token));
                if (completedTask == valueTask)
                {
                    if (timeoutCancellationTokenSource.Token.CanBeCanceled)
                    {
                        timeoutCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                    }

                    var result = valueTask.Result;
                    return (result == "WhatIWant");
                }

                if (getValueCancellationTokenSource.Token.CanBeCanceled)
                {
                    getValueCancellationTokenSource.Cancel ();
                }

                return false;
            }
        }

    } 
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### `GetValueUsingNamedPipe`

```cs
public async Task<string> GetValueUsingNamedPipe(CancellationTokenSource ct)
{
    var response = "";
    try
    {
        Task sendMsg = SendMessage ("MyMessage", ct);
        await sendMsg;
        response = await Listen(ct);
    } 
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "";
    }
    return response;
}
```

#### `SendMessage`

```cs
public async Task SendMessage(string message, CancellationTokenSource ct)
{
    try
    {
        using (var _pipeClientStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "MyPipe", PipeDirection.Out, PipeOptions.Asynchronous))
        {
            await _pipeClientStream.ConnectAsync (1000, ct.Token);

            var writer = new StreamWriter (_pipeClientStream) { AutoFlush = true };
            await writer.WriteLineAsync (message);
            await writer.WriteLineAsync (MessageFooter);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception)
    {
        await Task.FromCanceled(ct.Token);
    }
}
```

#### `Listen`

```cs
public async Task<string> Listen(CancellationTokenSource ct)
{
    try
    {
        if (ct.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            ct.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested ();
        }
        using (var _pipeClientStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "MyListenPipe", PipeDirection.In, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation))
        {
            await _pipeClientStream.ConnectAsync (ct.Token);
            if (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder ();
                var reader = new StreamReader (_pipeClientStream);
                do
                {
                    string line = await reader.ReadLineAsync ();

                    if (line == MessageFooter || line == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    sb.AppendLine (line);

                } while (true);

                return sb.ToString ();
            }
            return "";
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can please tell us what's the point of the `timeoutCancellationTokenSource` in your code? This whole `Task.WhenAny` and `Task.Delay` is unnecessary. You could specify a timeout at the `ctor` of the CTS or by calling the `CancelAfter`

Comment: Well, that code came from a stackoverflow question about how to start a task with a timeout. The idea is that after the timeout, we would just give up on the whole thing and just return false. For some reason I thought maybe it was a good idea to cancel the delay task, but perhaps it isn't required?

Comment: This is the post that shows how to use the ```Task.Delay..``` technique: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout

Comment: If you look the requirements of the question (that you have linked) then you can spot that he OP is talking about two separate timeouts / duration thresholds. In your case you have only a single timeout. Your request either succeed, fail or timeout. Do I understand your program correctly?

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my understanding your piece of software can finish in one of the following states:

- Succeeded
- Failed
- Timed out

You are not exposing the ability to cancel it on the top level. So, it is not cancelable.

Your explicit cancellation mechanism is not needed because:

1. If timeout occurs at the top level then this fact will be available for all async methods, which received the `CancellationToken`. The built-in BCL functions will check the token's validity so you don't have to worry about it.
2. `SendMessage` and `Listen` are called sequentially. So if former fails then latter won't be called.
3. After `connectAsync` your `IsCancellationRequested` is pointless. If `connectAsync` succeeded then this property won't be true. If it was not succeeded then you would not reach this line because your `Listen` function will be aborted.

On the other hand there is one place where it could make sense to check the `cancellationToken`. That's inside the `do-while` loop because the `ReadLineAsync` is not cancellable.

So let's put all this together with these in mind. I've converted your code into C# 8 if you don't mind.

#### Listen

```cs
public async Task<string> Listen(CancellationToken ct)
{
    try
    {
        await using var _pipeClientStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "MyListenPipe", PipeDirection.In, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation); 
        await _pipeClientStream.ConnectAsync(ct);

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using var reader = new StreamReader(_pipeClientStream);
        do
        {
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            string line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

            if (line == MessageFooter || line == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            sb.AppendLine(line);

        } while (true);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

- The `NamedPipeClientStream` is `IAsyncDisposable` that's why I used `await using`.
- The `StreamReader` is `IDisposable` that's why I used `using`.
- I've checked the `CancellationToken` before each `ReadLineAsync` because it is not cancellable.

#### SendMessage

```cs
public async Task SendMessage(string message, CancellationToken ct)
{
    await using var _pipeClientStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "MyPipe", PipeDirection.Out, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
    await _pipeClientStream.ConnectAsync(1000, ct);

    await using var writer = new StreamWriter(_pipeClientStream) { AutoFlush = true };
    await writer.WriteLineAsync(message.AsMemory(), ct);
    await writer.WriteLineAsync(MessageFooter.AsMemory(), ct);
}
```

- `WriteLineAsync` can accept `CancellationToken` only if it is called with a `ReadOnlyMemory` or with a `StringBuilder`. That's why I used `AsMemory`.
- `StreamWriter` is `IAsyncDisposable` that's why I used `await using`.

#### GetValueUsingNamedPipe

```cs
public async Task<string> GetValueUsingNamedPipe(CancellationToken ct)
{
    await SendMessage("MyMessage", ct);
    return await Listen(ct);
}
```

- The `sendMsg` variable is pointless because right after the assignment it is awaited then never used.
- I've removed the try-catch block because in that way the `TaskCancelledException` would be caught here.
- So basically if you wish you can inline this method into the `CheckForValue`

#### CheckForValue

```cs
public async Task<bool> CheckForValue()
{
    const int timeout = 300;
    try
    {
        using var timeoutTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);
        var result = await GetValueUsingNamedPipe(timeoutTokenSource.Token);
        return (result == "WhatIWant");
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException) //The actual type will be TimedOutTaskCanceledException
    {
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception) // GetValueUsingNamedPipe failed for some reason
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

- All the explicit cancellation calls are gone, because they are not needed. The cancellation fact will be propagated all the related parties and it will manifest in a `TaskCancelledException`.
- So it is much cleaner now. :D

I hope it helped you a bit.